# Button stops working after loading div via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two divs on the page: main div and secondary, which loads a separate html page using ajax. All the links within the main div trigerred by a click event continue to work correctly and reference the appropriate content, but none of the jquery outside this div works (such as the navigation).

Here's my jQuery:

```
    var url;
    $('.main a').live('click',function() {
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.secondary').load(url);
    return false;
    });
```

Can anyone help me why this isn't working? I think I am supposed to trigger a callback event but I am not sure how to do so. I know this question has been asked multiple times already (usually suggesting to use .live() or .on()), but none of those solutions seemed to work for me.

Edit: Here's a short fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/snDzF/ 
 So login is supposed to be a toggle bottle, Link 1, 2 and 3 load the html in the secondary right div. The login toggle button works up until I click one of the links to load the other page.

Comment: Please post all your script, cool?

Comment: If possible could you paste a http://jsfiddle.net/ link with your code

Comment: Are you saying event handlers for elements not in the main or secondary div stop working after you do `$('.secondary').load(url)`? If so, can you show an example of how you bind those event handlers?

Comment: you are rely on classes, may be the content that loaded by `secondary` also have elements with classes `main` or `secondary` ?

Comment: Please stop using `.live()` - delegation through `.on()` is preferred for many (mainly performance) reasons. Read more: http://bitovi.com/blog/2011/04/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live.html or http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/

Comment: @ahren .live() has to be used to bind to dynamically created elements

Comment: @VIDesignz `.on()` is the preferred way since jQuery 1.7+ and `.delegate()` since jQuery 1.4.3+  Read the docs here http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Added a fiddle that shows the structure.  Can't post the whole code since it has python incorporated into it and wouldn't work anyway.  I tried .on() but its not working for me either.

Comment: When you load new html to your div, are you also loading new scripts from that page?  It might be causing conflicts.. Can you show more code from maybe the page you are loading the page and the page you are loading into the div?

Comment: wirey, the page that I am loading does have scripts, but it is linked to the same css sheet and the same js sheet. Will that matter?

Comment: I remember I had the same issue.  I was loading jQuery on my main page, and also imported it on the page which I loaded into a div.  It cause my page to break so I removed the import on the secondary page and it fixed the issue

Comment: You need to clarify your question. When you say `loads a separate html page using ajax` I think you mean `insert html markup into secondaryDiv.` Your posted fiddle does not work because the event handlers are bound to elements that don't exist. You say that `none of the jquery outside this div works (such as the navigation`. But I see no navigation code or navigation related javascript. Please consider rewriting your question, keeping in mind that we are in the dark.

Comment: You were right wirey, I removed the reference to the .js file from the secondary page and it works. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @wirey Thanks for the reference! I didn't realize there was a new .on() feature that bound to dynamic elements...This will come in handy!

Comment: @wirey - You should submit your solution as an answer, so we SOers don't have to read through all the comments to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to remove loading any javascript files on the second frame. Can only load plain HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var url;
$('.main a').click(function(){
    url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.secondary').load(url);
});
```